# Can print web page using POS/Receipt printer?

Tags: php

I have an intranet web page that consist of only text (no images). I need to print this page using Receipt\POS printer to print it.

is it possible or not?

thanks

Comment: I've always generated a PDF for things like this.

Comment: which one is the easy way... (1). printing directly to paper or (2). export to pdf and print as a batch.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Two simple ways to do it, depending on how much interference you're willing to accept in your interface.

Firstly, you can just use JavaScript to trigger your receipt page/iframe to print. This option is a little klunky, as it requires the cashier to confirm the print in the system dialogue.

But secondly, you always have the option of sharing each station's printer on the network. Your server-side component can print directly to it. And if it's a *nix server, it's pretty easy to do once each station's printer has added to / shared with the server. In PHP (with CUPs installed, I imagine):

```
// attempt to pipe to 'lp -d printername'
if (`echo "{$text}" | lp -d {$printer_name}`) {
    // print successful
    return true;
} else {
    // print failed
    return false;
}
```

If you're running a windows server, it's probably much more complicated.